# onClick preencher input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, aplicação-web

Queria fazer um menu de opções (buttons) no meu site, e ao clicar neles é carregado um valor ao input.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer um script que ao clicar no botão, o campo abaixo fosse preenchido com algum valor, mas não tive nenhum sucesso com isso.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnCorreioEletronico").on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("RecursosTI").value == "Correio Eletronico";
}
```

O ideal também é que fosse possível separar cada opção com uma vírgula, e que também fosse possível remover com uma espécie de Toggle.

Alguem pode me ajudar com isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se é isso que você procura:

```js
$(document).ready(_ => {
    
    const added = [],
    input = document.getElementById("RecursoTI");

    $('button').on('click', ev => {
    
    const recurso = ev.currentTarget.innerText,    
    idx = added.indexOf(recurso);
    
    if (idx === -1) {added.push(recurso);}
    
    else {
    
        added.splice(idx, 1);
    
    }
    
    input.value = added.join(',');
    
    });
    
});
```

```css
button {margin-right: 5px;}

input {display: block; margin: 10px 0; width: 100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Correio Eletrônico</button>
<button>Impressão</button>
<button>Note</button>
<button>Desktop</button>

<input type="text" id="RecursoTI" />
```